# simple odata client filter nested collection

Tags: c#, odata, simple.odata.client

I have the following odata query:

```
/Places?$filter=CountryCode eq 'de'&$expand=Images($filter=IsCover eq true)
```

The `Places` has a `collection` of `Images`. This query returns back all places for "DE" and for each place only the `Image` that has the property `IsCover true`

How can I write this in fluent API?

I tried following:

```
return await _oDataClient
                .For<Place>()
                .Filter(p => p.CountryCode == "DE"))
                .Expand(f => f.Images.Where(i => i.IsCover == true))
                .FindEntriesAsync();
```

but it keeps giving and exception. Is there any way to write this in fluent API?

Comment: This isn't supported by Simple.Odata.Client. See [this outstanding issue.](https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client/issues/200)